# Adding an on/off switch for my furnace fan

Tags: hvac

Here is my situation,  I want to be able to run the blower on my furnace during the summer so that the cool basement air can be circulated thought the house. I live in an old house and the thermostat only has two wires running to it, and I believe that it is therefor unable to operate just the furnace fan. I remember being younger and the furnace we had at home just had a simple push/pull switch attached to the furnace that turned on the furnace fan, but my new furnace doesn't have such a button. I don't want to run new wires to the thermostat, so I'm wondering if there are other options. Can I install an on/off switch directly on the furnace somehow? I have a carrier performace 80 furnace, model number 58CTA070. Thanks do any help!

Comment: Typically a furnace circulates air only in the heated space (some of the vents are supply that blow hot air and some of them are return, that suck back cold air). Running the fan will only circulate basement air if the cold air return is actually in the basement. Is this your situation?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the cold air return is in the basement

Answer (score 2):

Your thermostat is probably connected to the R and W/W1 terminals on the furnace. To run just the fan, you would need to add a switch connected to the R and G terminals.

Answer (score 0):

Put a jumper wire (just a wire) connecting R and G. Worked for me! Picture (horizontal green wire between R and G):

[image]

Comment: This won't work in the OP's case, because *the thermostat only has two wires running to it*, which are presumably red and white.  The OP has no green wire running to the thermostat.